# Testing all available fonts

Tags: fontsize

I need to display some very small numbers in my document (3-5 pt). I want to test out all available fonts within my installation at this size, to find which produces the most readable numbers. Is there a simple way to produce this output (i.e. generate a document which contains a sample text displayed in all fonts at the specified size)??

Comment: fonts available for latex ord lualatex/xelatex or both?

Comment: I will award the bounty to an answer that works in XeTeX. When I first posted the question, I had not yet discovered XeTeX.

Comment: You can get the font list with `fc-list`, see [How to get a list of all available (TTF-) Fonts with XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12881/5245).

Comment: `fc-list` shows the open and true type fonts of the TeX system only with a special config file, eg the TeX Gyre fonts

Comment: @Herbert What do you mean by *special config file*? The fonts have to ship another file to make it appear within `fc-list`?

Comment: @Marco: `fc-cache` looks by default only in the system font directories but not in the ones from TeX, eg: `$TEXMF/fonts/opentype/`

Comment: @Herbert You're right, thanks for the info.

Comment: Is there a LaTeX (pdflatex) solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following ConTeXt/LuaTeX solution prints a pdf with all available fonts in the font size 4pt. Beware: It takes a long time to process and consumes lots of memory.

**Edit:** I replaced the ugly unix command dependency of `cut` with a lua solution.

```
\def\sample{Some Sample text\crlf}
\def\testfont#1{\definedfont[name:#1 at 4pt] #1: \sample}

\starttext

\executesystemcommand {mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=* > \jobname.filelist}
\startluacode
    myfile = assert(io.open('\jobname.filelist', 'r'))
    for line in myfile:lines() do
        local first, second, third = line:match '(%S+)'
        if first~= nil then
            context('\\testfont{')
            context(line)
            context('}')
        end
    end
    myfile:close()
\stopluacode

\stoptext
```

This is a screenshot of the first few fonts:

[image: result]

**Edit:**

Unfortunately there is no method for reading the database directly from within Lua (see: [How do I get a list of all available fonts for luaotfload](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14162/5245)).   You either have to use an external command or read in the database file (`otlf-names.lua` for LaTeX). Neither solution is optimal.

Comment: Why do you say that there is no method of reading the database in lua? After all, `mtx-fonts` is a lua script, that uses `fonts.name.load` function defined in `font-syn.lua` to read the font database. In principle, you can just rewrite `list_matches` function of `mtx-fonts` to fit your needs.

Comment: @Aditya I was referring to Khaled's comment to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14162/5245. I don't know of any way to read in the database without directly reading the database file or parsing external programs output. I'll have a look at the files you mentioned. Maybe I can come up with a better solution. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this code to create a font catalog of our available fonts. However, I have more than 6000 fonts available, and ConTeXt runs out of node memory very soon. I read [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50327/how-to-increase-the-node-memory-size-in-context) that there is no real way (or need) of increasing the node memory; that if you ran out of node memory is because your code is wrong. Is there any way of doing this over a big database of fonts (say, more than 5000 font files)?

Comment: @ElAndi I just ran the code on a font library of about 5800 fonts and it seemed to work fine. Are you sure you're not just running out of memory? Loading the font cache consumed almost 18GiB of RAM here.

Comment: That's the thing, it seems. I "only" have 16 GiB... Will need to find a monster to compile this. No complains, tho. Good to see the limits.

Comment: Split up the list into smaller chunks your system can handle. Then merge the pages.

Comment: May I ask for a complete file? Embedding this into my latex file causes `! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \starttext` and searches don't clarify what this belongs to. (running lualatex)