# LaTeX font identification

Tags: fonts

I've been struggling with identifying this beautiful font

[image]

From the properties of the Pdf file I think it's Arial ! and I found in some forums this it's a commercial font and the good alternative is helvet (I am using Ubuntu) ! But After compiling, it doesn't look the same !

Here are the list of fonts that the Pdf shows :

[image]

I thought it's Arial because it's the font dominating ! but I think I was wrong, how can I have that font in LateX ?

Comment: If you don't care about licensing there is a way to install microsoft fonts in ubuntu... google for it (But I don't know how you will find if Arial is what you are looking for)

Comment: I just want a  font like the one in the the first image ! If somebody can tell me what package I can use to have a similar output !

Comment: you can start by downloading latex-fonts-extra... then I can make you a script to test all the available fonts with a text of your choise and sent it to you to choose whatever you think is close to that...

Comment: Sounds good, I have full Tex installed ! thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's Arial.The `o` is too narrow.

Comment: Nice... Are you programming in c++ too? I am asking because it is easy for me to make a qt code for this task... It will be a user friendly app if you want to install qtcreator... If not I will try to make a python or c app (i think only build-essentials will be ok then)

Comment: Check this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12881/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-available-ttf-fonts-with-xetex but I think @UlrikeFischer found what you want

Comment: Nope it's not ! I have tried that earlier and found that there are too many differences especially in upper case characters !

As for the script ! I also used an alternative earlier by checking FontCatalogue (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), the website shows many font catalogs with tex code, and I narrowed the search to Fonts With Math Support since the document that I have have math formulas, yet I wasn't fortunate. I guess I'll try to tweak but customizing the space length between each line in the text and using lettrine for the first letter.

Comment: font-identifying questions are besser suited at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is `cmbright`: `g` and `o` correspond:

[image]

Comment: Probably, but the output is a bit Boldface, the image is not ! but that's the best candidate ! Thanks

Comment: Welcome! This was not visible in your post. Note `cmbright` has a semi-bold version, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is `cmbright`. Here is the output of the same text above.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=2, findent=3pt, nindent=0pt]{S}{}mart 
devices are rapidly emerging as popular appliances with increasingly powerful computing, networking, and sensing capabilities. Perhaps the most successful examples of such devices so far are smartphones and tablets, which in their current generation are far more powerful than early personal computers (PCs). One of the key differences between such “smart" devices and traditional “non-smart" appliances is that they offer the possibility to easily incorporate third-party applications through online markets (Figure 1.1 depicts such differences)\footnote{here}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, as @Bernard stated it's it's cmbright. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like standard computer modern. But sans serif fonts are not always easy to differentiate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
devices are rapidly emerging as popular\\
networking
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not the same `g`, and the `o` is a bit too narrow.

Comment: It's not, upper case characters don't like the same ! thank you.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, you are right, it was a bit late yesterday ;-). But I got the family right ;-).